# Cant boot up. dell_smm_hwmon: unable to get SMM Dell signature

Tags: boot, dell, xps, signature

Using XPS 9720 and installed a fresh ubuntu 22.04 LTS over windows. Everything was going fine until i rebooted the system.

Now it doesnt boot and shows me the message:

dell_smm_hwmon: unable to get SMM Dell signature

EDIT: 22.04 not 20.04

To provide even more details: this install is done on a new SSD (slot1) and the stock  SSD (moved to slot2) is wiped

Comment: I am facing the same issue. @ubunbro Did you find a solution?